# Using wordpress functions in class and change my code to OOP PHP

Tags: php, functions

I try to change all my code to OOP and I'm beginner in OOP and PHP
This worked, but when I changed my code to OOP, so that I could use my class in more places

```
function advanza_form_shortcode() {

    // Display the Advanza form with a shortcode
    $site_id = get_option('advanza_form_site_id');
    $affiliate_id = get_option('advanza_form_affiliate_id');
    $redirection = get_option('advanza_form_thankyou_page');
    $url = "https://advanzaservices.com/wp/singleform.php?site_id={$site_id}&affiliate_id={$affiliate_id}&thankyou={$redirection}";

    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    if ( is_array( $response ) ) {
        $header = wp_remote_retrieve_headers($response['headers']); // array of http header lines
        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response); // use the content
        $status_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);

        if($status_code == 200) {
            return $body;
        } else {
            return $status_code;
        }
   }
} add_shortcode( 'advanza-form', 'advanza_form_shortcode' );
```

I don't understand why this didn't work, I tried a lot and it seems like I don't get it.

```
class advanza_form {
    public $site_id;
    public $affiliate_id;
    public $redirection;
    public $url;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->site_id = get_option('advanza_form_site_id');
        $this->affiliate_id = get_option('advanza_form_affiliate_id');
        $this->redirection = get_option('advanza_form_thankyou_page');
        $this->url = "https://advanzaservices.com/wp/singleform.php?site_id={$this->site_id}&affiliate_id={$this->affiliate_id}&thankyou={$this->redirection}";
    }

    public function display() {
        $response = wp_remote_get( $this->url );
        $header = wp_remote_retrieve_headers($this->response['headers']); // array of http header lines
        $status_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($this->response);

        try {
            if($status_code == 200) {
                $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
            } else {
                return $status_code;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }// end try/catch

        return $body;
    }

    function debug() {
        echo 'Site ID: ' . $this->site_id . '<br>';
        echo 'Affiliate ID: ' . $this->affiliate_id . '<br>';
        echo 'Redirection: ' . $this->redirection . '<br>';
        echo 'URL: ' . $this->url . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Here I create my shortcode

```
function advanza_form_shortcode() {

    // Display the Advanza form with a shortcode
    $form = new advanza_form;
    $form->display();
    // $form->debug();

}
add_shortcode( 'advanza-form', 'advanza_form_shortcode' );
```

Comment: You haven't used `add_shortcode()` anywhere in the new code...

Comment: Woops my bad, I use it here /*
 * Create shortcode functionality
 */
function advanza_form_shortcode() {

 // Display the Advanza form with a shortcode
 $form = new advanza_form;
 $form->display();
 // $form->debug();

}
add_shortcode( 'advanza-form', 'advanza_form_shortcode' );

Comment: Can you include that in the question please.

Comment: I did! Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: you need to return the output in `advanza_form_shortcode()`, like so `return $form->display();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for all the suggestions and answers. I have fixed it, see my code below:

```
class advanza_form {
// Class properties defined using PHP Coding Guidelines and taking security measures: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php
public $site_id;
public $affiliate_id;
public $redirection;
protected $url;
private $response;
private $header; // For debugging
public $status_code; // For debugging

public function __construct() {
    $this->site_id = get_option('advanza_form_site_id');
    $this->affiliate_id = get_option('advanza_form_affiliate_id');
    $this->redirection = get_option('advanza_form_thankyou_page');
    $this->url = "https://advanzaservices.com/wp/singleform.php?site_id={$this->site_id}&affiliate_id={$this->affiliate_id}&thankyou={$this->redirection}";
    $this->response = wp_remote_get( $this->url );
    $this->header = wp_remote_retrieve_headers( $this->response ); // array of http header lines
    $this->status_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $this->response );
}

public function display() {
    try {
        if($this->status_code == 200) {
            $html = wp_remote_retrieve_body($this->response);
        } else {
            return $this->status_code;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }// end try/catch

    return $html;
}

public function debug() {
    $last_modified = wp_remote_retrieve_header( $this->response, 'last-modified' );
    echo '<h1>Debug information</h1>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<strong>Site ID:</strong> ' . $this->site_id . '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Affiliate ID:</strong> ' . $this->affiliate_id . '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Redirection:</strong> ' . $this->redirection . '<br>';
    echo '<strong>URL:</strong> ' . $this->url . '<br>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<h2>Technical details</h2>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo '<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes" target="_blank"><strong>HTTP status code:</strong></a> ' . $this->status_code . '<br>';
    echo '<strong>Headers:</strong> '; var_export($this->header);
    echo '</p>';
    // error: Invalid or no affiliate_id supplied
}
}
```

The shortcode

```
function advanza_form_shortcode() {
    // Display the Advanza form with a shortcode
    $form = new advanza_form;
    // For debugging
    // $form->debug();
    return $form->display();
}
add_shortcode( 'advanza-form', 'advanza_form_shortcode' );
```